# Check If Record Has References

Tags: doctrine-orm

I wonder if there is any way to find out if a record has references.

I have the following entity:

```
class Item extends Entity
{
    /**
     * @Id @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(name="id")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Citation", mappedBy="citation")
     */
    protected $citedIn;

    /**
     * @Column(name="stamped", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $stamped;

    /** ... rest of the code ... */

}
```

And I want to perform the following check:

```
$qb
    ->select("
        COUNT(i.id),
        WHEN (i.stamped = true) THEN 'stamped'
        WHEN (i.citedIn IS NOT NULL) THEN 'cited'
        ELSE 'just started'
        END current_status
    ")
    ->from(Entity\Item::class, 'i')
    ->groupBy('current_status');
```

Note that I tried to use  `i.citedIn IS NOT NULL`, but it didn't work. What could I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a `OneToMany` relationship I think you need to use `IS NOT EMPTY` instead of `IS NOT NULL`. Doctrine will create an empty ArrayCollection for each entity, so technically it's not null, because it's an empty array.

## Update

If that doesn't work, try `NOT INSTANCE OF YourApp\Model\Citation`.